# Exact time measurement for performance testing

Tags: c#, .net, performance, testing

What is the most exact way of seeing how long something, for example a method call, took in code?

The easiest and quickest I would guess is this:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
{
    // Do some work
}
TimeSpan timeItTook = DateTime.Now - start;
```

But how exact is this? Are there better ways?

Comment: You won't bet on .NET classes because you don't know how they work? Does that mean you're afraid to use the String class also? Anyway, the documentation of the Stopwatch class explicitly says that it is using the QueryPerformanceCounter() Win32 API function.

Comment: The String class has nothing to do with this. If Stopwatch exists in .NET how should I know it's better than QueryPerformanceCounter ? which is the best option that can exists !!

Comment: @pixel3cs: downvoting a correct answer because you got criticized in a a comment is not very mature

Comment: @pixel3cs But you had time reading the Kernel32 api?

Answer (score 762, accepted):

A better way is to use the Stopwatch class:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
// ...

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();

// ...

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Elapsed={0}",sw.Elapsed);
```

Comment: If you need to know the resolution of the Stopwatch timings on a particular machine then you can use the Stopwatch.Frequency property.

Comment: Also, the Stopwatch.StartNew() static method is a convenient way to both create and start the Stopwatch on a single line.

Comment: [MS Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 198):

As others have said, `Stopwatch` is a good class to use here. You can wrap it in a helpful method:

```
public static TimeSpan Time(Action action)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    action();
    stopwatch.Stop();
    return stopwatch.Elapsed;
}
```

(Note the use of `Stopwatch.StartNew()`. I prefer this to creating a Stopwatch and then calling `Start()` in terms of simplicity.) Obviously this incurs the hit of invoking a delegate, but in the vast majority of cases that won't be relevant. You'd then write:

```
TimeSpan time = StopwatchUtil.Time(() =>
{
    // Do some work
});
```

You could even make an `ITimer` interface for this, with implementations of `StopwatchTimer,` `CpuTimer` etc where available.

Comment: @JonSkeet When invoking this utility (i.e. as per the second code sample) with in a loop, it appears the call to `action()` incurs an increased cost on the first iteration. Could you explain what is happening here, if that's possible within a comment?! Many thanks..

Comment: @ppejovic: It's probably the cost of JIT compilation, or possibly the cost of initializing the class used by the lambda expression. Just how big is this "increased cost"?

Comment: @JonSkeet Well I'm actually leaving the lambda empty :), so the usage is identical to your sample. It's a difference between about 500+ ticks on the first iteration, and 4 on subsequent. If I'm right, JIT'ing is by default disabled in VS when debugging? I can post this as a question if easier.. cheers

Comment: @ppejovic: If you're *debugging* then you should ignore all performance results completely. But JIT compilation occurs whether or not you're debugging, just with different optimizations.

Comment: Dear Jon, I'm sorry but this method will not give the correct result in every usages. If you use "System.Threading.Tasks.Task" this static method will not measure elapsed time. An ex: TimeSpan timeElapsed = JonSkeetCode.Time(() => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AddNumberAndPrintAll(5))); Console.WriteLine(timeElapsed); // if you run that two lines of code; code will reach Console.WriteLine line before the measurement. ( AddNumberAndPrintAll is some silly heavy-work method. )

Comment: @NAKRO: Well that's because the "work" you've said to do is just "start a new task". And that really *doesn't* take long. So yes, it *does* give the correct result, but you're not measuring what you really want to measure. If you want to measure how long it takes for the task to complete, then you need to wait for it to finish.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you very much for your quick answer. So, I can't use this method to measure "parallel jobs" ? -Or- Am I making a mistake with using Task.Factory.StartNew ? Thanks again...

Comment: @NAKRO: Well you can, but you need to make sure that the "action" involved both starts all the tasks *and waits for them to finish*.

Answer (score 93):

As others said, `Stopwatch` should be the right tool for this. There can be few improvements made to it though, see this thread specifically: [Benchmarking small code samples in C#, can this implementation be improved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047218/benchmarking-small-code-samples-in-c-can-this-implementation-be-improved).

I have seen some useful tips by [Thomas Maierhofer here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61964/Performance-Tests-Precise-Run-Time-Measurements-wi)

Basically his code looks like:

```
//prevent the JIT Compiler from optimizing Fkt calls away
long seed = Environment.TickCount;

//use the second Core/Processor for the test
Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity = new IntPtr(2);

//prevent "Normal" Processes from interrupting Threads
Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;

//prevent "Normal" Threads from interrupting this thread
Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;

//warm up
method();

var stopwatch = new Stopwatch()
for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++)
{
    stopwatch.Reset();
    stopwatch.Start();
    for (int j = 0; j < iterations; j++)
        method();
    stopwatch.Stop();
    print stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

Another approach is to rely on `Process.TotalProcessTime` to measure how long the CPU has been kept busy *running the very code/process*, [*as shown here*](http://kristofverbiest.blogspot.in/2008/10/beware-of-stopwatch.html) This can reflect more real scenario since no other process affects the measurement. It does something like:

```
 var start = Process.GetCurrentProcess().TotalProcessorTime;
 method();
 var stop = Process.GetCurrentProcess().TotalProcessorTime;
 print (end - begin).TotalMilliseconds;
```

A naked, detailed implementation of the [samething can be found here.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31152/ExecutionStopwatch?msg=4547000#xx4547000xx)

I wrote a helper class to perform both in an easy to use manner:

```
public class Clock
{
    interface IStopwatch
    {
        bool IsRunning { get; }
        TimeSpan Elapsed { get; }

        void Start();
        void Stop();
        void Reset();
    }



    class TimeWatch : IStopwatch
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        public TimeSpan Elapsed
        {
            get { return stopwatch.Elapsed; }
        }

        public bool IsRunning
        {
            get { return stopwatch.IsRunning; }
        }



        public TimeWatch()
        {
            if (!Stopwatch.IsHighResolution)
                throw new NotSupportedException("Your hardware doesn't support high resolution counter");

            //prevent the JIT Compiler from optimizing Fkt calls away
            long seed = Environment.TickCount;

            //use the second Core/Processor for the test
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity = new IntPtr(2);

            //prevent "Normal" Processes from interrupting Threads
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;

            //prevent "Normal" Threads from interrupting this thread
            Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
        }



        public void Start()
        {
            stopwatch.Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            stopwatch.Reset();
        }
    }



    class CpuWatch : IStopwatch
    {
        TimeSpan startTime;
        TimeSpan endTime;
        bool isRunning;



        public TimeSpan Elapsed
        {
            get
            {
                if (IsRunning)
                    throw new NotImplementedException("Getting elapsed span while watch is running is not implemented");

                return endTime - startTime;
            }
        }

        public bool IsRunning
        {
            get { return isRunning; }
        }



        public void Start()
        {
            startTime = Process.GetCurrentProcess().TotalProcessorTime;
            isRunning = true;
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            endTime = Process.GetCurrentProcess().TotalProcessorTime;
            isRunning = false;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            startTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
            endTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
        }
    }



    public static void BenchmarkTime(Action action, int iterations = 10000)
    {
        Benchmark<TimeWatch>(action, iterations);
    }

    static void Benchmark<T>(Action action, int iterations) where T : IStopwatch, new()
    {
        //clean Garbage
        GC.Collect();

        //wait for the finalizer queue to empty
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        //clean Garbage
        GC.Collect();

        //warm up
        action();

        var stopwatch = new T();
        var timings = new double[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < timings.Length; i++)
        {
            stopwatch.Reset();
            stopwatch.Start();
            for (int j = 0; j < iterations; j++)
                action();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            timings[i] = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            print timings[i];
        }
        print "normalized mean: " + timings.NormalizedMean().ToString();
    }

    public static void BenchmarkCpu(Action action, int iterations = 10000)
    {
        Benchmark<CpuWatch>(action, iterations);
    }
}
```

Just call

```
Clock.BenchmarkTime(() =>
{
    //code

}, 10000000);
```

or

```
Clock.BenchmarkCpu(() =>
{
    //code

}, 10000000);
```

The last part of the `Clock` is the tricky part. If you want to display the final timing, its up to you to choose what sort of timing you want. I wrote an extension method `NormalizedMean` which gives you the mean of the read timings *discarding the noise.* I mean I calculate the the deviation of each timing from the actual mean, and then I discard the values which was farer (only the slower ones) from the **mean of deviation** (called absolute deviation; note that its not the often heard standard deviation), and finally return the mean of remaining values. This means, for instance, if timed values are `{ 1, 2, 3, 2, 100 }` (in ms or whatever), it discards `100`, and returns the mean of `{ 1, 2, 3, 2 }` which is `2`. Or if timings are `{ 240, 220, 200, 220, 220, 270 }`, it discards `270`, and returns the mean of `{ 240, 220, 200, 220, 220 }` which is `220`.

```
public static double NormalizedMean(this ICollection<double> values)
{
    if (values.Count == 0)
        return double.NaN;

    var deviations = values.Deviations().ToArray();
    var meanDeviation = deviations.Sum(t => Math.Abs(t.Item2)) / values.Count;
    return deviations.Where(t => t.Item2 > 0 || Math.Abs(t.Item2) <= meanDeviation).Average(t => t.Item1);
}

public static IEnumerable<Tuple<double, double>> Deviations(this ICollection<double> values)
{
    if (values.Count == 0)
        yield break;

    var avg = values.Average();
    foreach (var d in values)
        yield return Tuple.Create(d, avg - d);
}
```

Comment: Good details on controlling the environment and ignoring the spikes! Thanks.

Comment: In the original example, the `long seed = Environment.TickCount;` was used as input to the algorithm under test, [in order to make it non-deterministic](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61964/Performance-Tests-Precise-Run-Time-Measurements-wi?msg=4548708#xx4548708xx) and prevent it from being evaluated at compile-time.  That seed is not being used here.

Comment: what about the `values.Deviations()`method.. ? (maybe I can do it myself but it would be nice with the experts input)

Comment: I liked the proposed the solution of using the actual CPU time, only note that the `TotalProcessorTime` has a "low" resolution. See also [How we can reduce the resolution of myProcess.TotalProcessorTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29676704/how-we-can-reduce-the-resolution-of-myprocess-totalprocessortime)

Answer (score 14):

Use the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class

Comment: Downvoters: we'll be happy to know what's wrong!

Comment: Guess because you answered the same in nearly the same time with less description. (I didnt' upvote or downvote you)

Answer (score 13):

System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch is designed for this task.

Comment: See the comments on the question above, and you'll see why.

Answer (score 5):

Stopwatch is fine, but loop the work 10^6 times, then divide by 10^6.
You'll get a lot more precision.

Comment: Good point, but would still need something to take the time on those 10^6 times :)

Comment: Put Stopwatch around the whole thing. I thought that was clear.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUrl);
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();

timer.Start();

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();

response.Close();

timer.Stop();
```

Comment: Mind sharing the type of the variable timer and how to read out the time that passed?