How can I correctly measure the time, needed for operations and instructions, in a multi-threaded C# application, using NLog?
I have a background in UNIX server programming, where speed analysis is extremely simple: just add logs and verify the differences between subsequent entries.
This way of working, however, seems to be bogus in my current application: a C# multi-threaded application based on NLog (the latter for logging purposes).
The source I'm testing is the following:
foreach (var missionpart in mission.missionParts)
{
    _logger.Debug($"GetmissionsTelegram : currently dealing with missionPart with Id=[{missionpart.Id}]");
    if (missionpart.ProductId != null)
    {
        if (products.Where(o => o.Id == missionpart.ProductId).FirstOrDefault() == null)
        {
            add_mission = false;
        }
    }
    _logger.Debug($"GetmissionsTelegram : missionPart with Id=[{missionpart.Id}] is dealt with.");
}

_logger.Debug($"GetmissionsTelegram : will be added=[{addmission}]");

From this piece of code, you can easily see that the line, containing "is dealt with" should immediately be followed, either by a "currently dealing" or by a "will be added" line. This is not the case, as you can see from the following logfile excerpts:
...
2024-10-17 16:58:13.2446 | GetJobsTelegram : jobPart with Id=[37370] is dealt with.
2024-10-17 16:58:24.1662 | GetJobsTelegram : currently dealing with jobPart with Id=[37371]
...
2024-10-17 17:02:31.9896 | GetJobsTelegram : jobPart with Id=[37320] is dealt with.
2024-10-17 17:02:44.9066 | GetJobsTelegram : currently dealing with jobPart with Id=[37321]
...
2024-10-17 17:04:44.1077 | GetJobsTelegram : jobPart with Id=[37305] is dealt with.
2024-10-17 17:04:55.9323 | GetJobsTelegram : currently dealing with jobPart with Id=[37306]

As you can see, the timestamps go up to nine seconds or even more!
I can confirm that my application indeed takes a long time to get everything done, so in case NLog does some buffering (which seems to be normal in Windows technology), this only shifts the problem into the uselessness of the logs, but the problem remains.
... or maybe there is a way to immediately jump to the source of the problem: is there a way to say to a multi-threaded C# application:

You do not continue your other threads until this task is finished.

What can I try next?

Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969290/exact-time-measurement-for-performance-testing It talks about Stopwatch class, which you could use (and for example ElapsedTicks property).

And for question "You do not continue your other threads until this task is finished." - you need to look into some synchronization mechanisms. And that greatly depends on how you want to do it and using what tools. For example there's Thread.Join method. If you are using Task, then you could call await

@MichałTurczyn: thanks a lot for your replies: that Stopwatch class is indeed more fiable than the buffered NLog logs' timestamps. On the other hand, I have replaced my products (which was a List<>) by a Dictionary<>, having Id as an indexing mechanism, and this solved the original question of the bad performance.

@Dominique what you call simple in Unix is simply wrong and was superceded by tracing using dtrace etc a long time ago. Writing to log files is so coarse and expensive that the timings are skewed. The current trend is to use OpenTelemetry traces and metrics. .NET always supported both tracing and metrics (as Performance counters) and in .NET Core, ActivitySource, Activity and Metrics classes provide OpenTelemetry traces and metrics

Instead of trying to reconstruct actions from logs, the Activity class can be used to record the start, end and result of an opearation.

How about using an external Performance Profiler application like ANTS or dotTrace or the one built into Visual Studio?

NLog outputs its timestamps in local time by default, as this is expected by most first time users. The conversion from machine time to regional local time has an overhead, so NLog uses a cached-timesource (FastLocal) by default that only refreshes every 15 msec (Follows Environment.TickCount)
You can change the timesource to one with higher precision like this:
<nlog>
    <time type="AccurateUTC" />
    <!-- Rest of Configuration -->
</nlog>

Notice if you are planning to benchmark something that is sub-millisecond, then I really recommend checking out BenchmarkDotNet
But your problems doesn't seem to come from millisecond-time-precision, since your timings are several seconds apart. So these timings are probably not directly related to NLog, but maybe caused by stalls from the garbage collector or thread starvation? Can also be that you are using synchronous logging and not using NLog AsyncWrapper for optimal performance ?
See also: https://blog.machinezoo.com/how-to-configure-nlog-time-source
See also: https://blog.machinezoo.com/nlog-timestamps-with-millisecond
See also: https://caraulean.com/2016/timestamp-accuracy-and-resolution-in-nlog/

The commandline command set | findstr /I "Tick" does not yield any result. Do I need to create this "TickCount" as an environment variable for my entire computer or can I just add it in my Application.config file? If yes, how?

I have no idea about how to change the time-resolution of the API-method Environment.TickCount. I recommend that you just change NLog to use the time-source AccurateUTC.
